# How I can list files from REMOTE HOST directory using Python?

Tags: python, operating-system

I need get the list of files from a **remote host directory**, running the code in my local machine.

Is something like `os.listdir()` at **remote host machine**, NOT is `os.lisdir()` in the local machine that runs the python code.

In bash this command works
`ssh user@host "find /remote/path/ -name "pattern*" -mmin -15" > /local/path/last_files.txt`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/filesys.html

Comment: Sounds like you want `os.listdir()`.

Comment: Is like `os.listdir()` but in a host machine, not in the local machine that runs the code

Comment: If my answer helped please mark as accepted so others will know they can use this information. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option for running commands on a remote machine is via ssh with [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko).

A couple of examples of how to use the library and issue a command to the remote system:

```
import base64
import paramiko

# Let's assign an RSA SSH key to the 'key' variable
key = paramiko.RSAKey(data=base64.b64decode(b'AAA...'))

# And create a client instance.
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Create an object to store our key  
host_keys = client.get_host_keys()
# Add our key to 'host_keys'
host_keys.add('ssh.example.com', 'ssh-rsa', key)

# Connect to our client; you will need 
# to know/use for the remote account:
#
#   IP/Hostname of target
#   A username 
#   A password
client.connect('IP_HOSTNAME', username='THE_USER', password='THE_PASSWORD')

# Assign our input, output and error variables to
# to a command we will be issuing to the remote 
# system 
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(
    'find /path/data/ -name "pattern*" -mmin -15'
)

# We iterate over stdout
for line in stdout:
    print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))

# And finally we close the connection to our client
client.close()
```

As pointed out by the OP, if we already have a known hosts file locally we can do things slightly different:

```
import base64
import paramiko

# And create a client instance.
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Create a 'host_keys' object and load
# our local known hosts  
host_keys = client.load_system_host_keys()

# Connect to our client; you will need 
# to know/use for the remote account:
#
#   IP/Hostname of target
#   A username 
#   A password
client.connect('IP_HOSTNAME', username='THE_USER', password='THE_PASSWORD')

# Assign our input, output and error variables to
# to a command we will be issuing to the remote 
# system 
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(
    'find /path/data/ -name "pattern*" -mmin -15'
)

# We iterate over stdout
for line in stdout:
    print('... ' + line.strip('\n'))

# And finally we close the connection to our client
client.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. Just needed to change the rsa keys. I ended up using the local known hosts using `client.load_system_host_keys()` because it was easier in my case since i had them loaded in my environment.

Comment: Cool glad to help, cheers for the feedback.

Comment: Does this find program also search subdirectories? How would I return results that are *only* in the parent `/path/data` directory and not files in a sub-directory of `data`?

Comment: You can read the man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

Comment: Is print(stdout) waiting for the ouput? I executed and seems not